# Bug before install okular snap

Tags: nautilus, 23.10

[image]

I'm going mad trying to fix this bug in Ubuntu 23.10. This happens after i installed okular snap. I tried whit `sudo chown -R $USER: $HOME`. I can't open the folder in the HOME directory and for some reason the folders are mirrored in the desktop.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Snaps are known to have permission issues, and `chown -R $USER: $HOME` definitely will not help fixing that.

As an workaround, you can install Okular 23.08.01 using APT.

```
sudo snap remove okular
sudo apt install okular
```

---

In case you cannot anymore access your home folder after using the command `chown -R $USER: $HOME`, the easiest way to fix is to create a new user.

Follow [the official tutorials](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/user-add.html.en) to create a new user account using the graphical user interface. Afterwards, logout, login with the new user. Back up any data you want to save from the home folder of the old user, and then delete the old user.

---

In case that somehow does not work because you lost access to your home folder, you can create a new user with the command line -

```
useradd -m -g users new-username
```

Then, create a password for the new user with

```
sudo passwd new-username
```

To give the new user sudo access,

```
sudo usermod -aG sudo new-username
```

---

**Please don't execute random terminal commands from the internet unless you know what they do. They can lead to disasters, like you losing access to your home folder (and worse)**

Answer (score 0):

You can remove desktop icons after installing snap okular:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-prefs
```

Then, click on "Activities" in the top left corner of your desktop and type "extentions" and click on the "Extentions" icon that will appear below to open it and then deactivate the "Desktop Icons NG (DING)" option. Move broken links from your home folder to the trash. And ready!